# Paste each cell in a defined range down X number of times, X being the length of another defined range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a matrix table: Column = Product Type, Rows = Monthly Unit Data

[image]

I'm writing VBA code that will conform the matrix into a normal table

[image]

So far I have this to populate the product types the number of times there are months.

```
Sub Create_Data_Table()

Dim RowCount As Long
Dim iRange As Range
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim xy As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
Sheets(1).Activate

x = Range("Products").Count
y = Range("MonthYear").Count

Range("Products").Copy
Sheets(2).Activate

Do While y > 0

    Range("E2").Select
    For Each iRange In Rows
        If Application.CountA(iRange) > 0 Then
            RowCount = RowCount + 1
        End If
    Next

    Range("Products").Copy
    Range("E" & RowCount + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    y = y - 1
    RowCount = 0
Loop
```

I'm having trouble coming up with a way to paste down the first month in the MonthYear range for the length of the Products range, and then repeat with the second cell (month) in the MonthYear range.

Any ideas of a more effective way to go about this?

[Added picture of desired output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vphmi.png)

Comment: Would be useful to populate a sample of the expected output in your second screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I would use formulas for this:

Formula to fill dates based on number of products:

> =OFFSET($B$1,0,ROUNDDOWN((ROW()-1)/COUNTA($A:$A),0))

[image]

Formula to fill products for each month:

> =OFFSET($A$2,MOD(ROW()-2,COUNTA($A:$A)-1),0)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for that formula solution Cameron. I may test that out to see if it works better than what I wrote. I am running this macro for dozens of these revenue templates, so ultimately I thought a macro would be useful. For anyone else that comes stumbling across this post, the solution I wrote is this:

```
Sub Create_Data_Table()

Dim my1 As Long
Dim my2 As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim i As Long


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

x = Range("Unit_FamSubDiv").count
y = Range("Unit_MonthYear").count
my1 = 1
my2 = x + 1
i = 1

Sheets(2).Activate

Do While y > 0

    Range("Unit_FamSubDiv").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("B" & 1 + my1 & ":B" & my2).Value = Range("Unit_MonthYear").Cells(i)

    y = y - 1
    my1 = my2
    my2 = my1 + x
    i = i + 1

Loop

Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=""Q""&ROUNDUP(MONTH(RC[1])/3,0)&""-""&RIGHT(YEAR(RC[1]),2)"
Range("A2").AutoFill Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

Range("F2").Value = "=XLOOKUP($B2,Unit_MonthYear,XLOOKUP($E2,Unit_FamSubDiv,ROUND(Unit_Fcst,0)))"
Range("F2").AutoFill Range("F2:F" & Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

Range("G2").Value = "=XLOOKUP($B2,ASP_MonthYear,XLOOKUP($E2,ASP_FamSubDiv,ROUND(ASP_Fcst,0)))"
Range("G2").AutoFill Range("G2:G" & Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

Range("H2").Value = "=XLOOKUP($B2,Rev_MonthYear,XLOOKUP($E2,Rev_FamSubDiv,ROUND(Rev_Fcst,0)))"
Range("H2").AutoFill Range("H2:H" & Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
```

End Sub

Comment: Hey Thanks @beeehop . One thing you can do is clean out some of the extraneous line that just slow down the code: `Range("A2").Select >>> ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ...` can be shortened to `Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = ...`. And Same thing with your copy pastes.